# EF Core get all where child of child has id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This seems rather simple but I cannot find an example anywhere, perhaps I'm looking for the wrong thing?

I have a Customer model and a Service model that each reference many CustomerServiceIssues. I have another model CustomerServiceIssues that contains a reference to a Customer and a reference to a Service.

Given a Customer Id, I want to get all related Services.

```
class CustomerModel{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<CustomerServiceIssuesModel> ServiceIssues {get;set;}
}
class ServiceModel{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<CustomerSeviceIssuesModel> ServiceIssues {get;set;}
}
class CustomerServiceIssuesModel{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public CustomerModel Customer {get;set;}
    public ServiceModel Service {get;set;}
}
```

Something like `_services.Where(x => x.ServiceIssues.Customer.Id == id)`

Comment: `_services.Where(x => x.ServiceIssues.Any(si => si.Customer.Id == id))`. I am still looking for a related question so I can mark it as such but if I can't find one I'll write an answer.

Comment: 2nd answer in the marked duplicate has the same thing as what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Many to Many - no idea why I didn't think of that. I'll leave this up for now for search reasons.